# Issue while calling web api controller from service in angular2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular

I am doing angular quick start tutorial.
So I am just Hero tutorial that specifies in angular2 quickstart on its website.
That runs fine for me. it binds static array data and perform CRUD.
But now I want to learn how to call web API method for getting data from database.

So I am calling webapi method in `getHeroes()` method of service and calling that method from init `method-ngOnInit()` of component but it gives error like this.
please correct if I am wrong.

Got this error, while calling Web api controller from my service in angular2

EXCEPTION:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for Http! (DashboardComponent -> HeroService -> Http)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23925
angular2.dev.js:23925 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23925
angular2.dev.js:23925 Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for Http! (DashboardComponent -> HeroService -> Http)
    at resolvePromise (angular2-polyfills.js:602)
    at angular2-polyfills.js:579
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:390)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (angular2.dev.js:2126)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:389)
    at Zone.run (angular2-polyfills.js:283)
    at angular2-polyfills.js:635
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular2-polyfills.js:423)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (angular2.dev.js:2118)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular2-polyfills.js:422)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23925
angular2-polyfills.js:528 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for Http! (DashboardComponent -> HeroService -> Http) ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoProviderErrorconsoleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:528
angular2-polyfills.js:530 Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for Http! (DashboardComponent -> HeroService -> Http)(…)consoleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:530
```

Here is my Hero service:

```
    import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
    import {Http,Response,Headers} from 'angular2/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import {Hero} from '/Scripts/FirstEx_Ts/Hero.ts';
    import {HEROES} from '/Scripts/FirstEx_Ts/MockHeros.ts';


    @Injectable()
   export class HeroService {



   private headers: Headers;

    constructor(private _http:Http) {
   }

 getHeroes(){

  return      this._http.get("http://localhost:54046/api/Heromanage/GetAllHeroes")
       .map((response: Response) => <Hero[]>response.json())
       .catch(this.handleError);
 }
 getHeroesSlowly() {
   return new Promise<Hero[]>(resolve =>
       setTimeout(() => resolve(HEROES), 2000) // 2 seconds
       );
 }

 getHero(id: number) {
   return Promise.resolve(HEROES).then(
       heroes => heroes.filter(hero => hero.id === id)[0]
       );
}

  private handleError(error: Response) {
   console.error(error);
   return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
 }
 }
```

And here is my Component from where I am calling service method:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http,Response,Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {Hero} from '/Scripts/FirstEx_Ts/Hero.ts';
import {HeroService} from '/Scripts/FirstEx_Ts/HeroService.ts';

@Component({
selector: 'my-dashboard',
providers: [HeroService],
templateUrl: '/Templates/DashboardComponent.html',
directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
styles: [ `
[class*='col-'] {
 float: left;
}
*, *:after, *:before {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
 }
h3 {
 text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0;
 }
[class*='col-'] {
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 }
  [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
  }
  .grid {
  margin: 0;
   }
  .col-1-4 {
   width: 25%;
  }
   .module {
    padding: 20px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #eee;
  max-height: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  border-radius: 2px;
    }
 h4 {
   position: relative;
  }
  .module:hover {
    background-color: #EEE;
    cursor: pointer;
      color: #607d8b;
  }
 .grid-pad {
   padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .grid-pad > [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
   padding-right: 20px;
   }
 @media (max-width: 600px) {
.module {
  font-size: 10px;
  max-height: 75px; }
  }
   @media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .grid {
  margin: 0;
    }
   .module {
  min-width: 60px;
   }
   }
 `]
  })
 export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
heroes: Hero[] = [];
constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private _heroService: HeroService) {
debugger;

}
**ngOnInit() {
    alert('hi');
    debugger;
     this._heroService
        .getHeroes()
        .subscribe((heroes:Hero[]) => this.heroes = data,
            error => console.log(error),
            () => console.log('Get all Items complete'));
}**
gotoDetail(hero: Hero) {
    let link = ['HeroDetail', { id: hero.id }];
    this._router.navigate(link);
  }

  }
```

Comment: what version of angular you are using, you have not added provider for HTTP. if anything gretaer than RC5 import `HttpModule`.

Answer (score 0):

you may try below,

**Angular version < RC5**

include `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in the providers array of Component metadata.

**Angular version >= RC5**

import `HttpModule` in the Module containing your component.

Hope this helps!!